# Loop through main folder but different subfolder and same name sub-subfolder in R

Tags: r, loops, netcdf4

I am working with .nc files. I want to loop through one main folder and multiple different subfolder but same name sub-subfolder. For example, the parent folder is 'A' with 6 different subfolders 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' and each of these folders have 2 sub-subfolders. Now 'B' has "historical" and "latest" sub-subfolders, 'C' has same subfolders "historical" and "latest" and so on. I want combine all the "latest" sub-subfolder files from folders 'B', 'C' and so on.

I wrote the following command, this gives me all the historical and latest subfolders files.

```
files <- list.files("/Users/ritikakhurana/Open Modeling Group Dropbox/COACCH/climate/A", pattern=".+.nc", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
"/Users/ritikakhurana/Open Modeling Group Dropbox/COACCH/climate/A/B/historical/198412-200511.nc"
[54] "/Users/ritikakhurana/Open Modeling Group Dropbox/COACCH/climate/A/B/latest/200512-203011.nc"      
and so on
```

Can someone please correct me?

Thanks,

Ritika

Comment: I'm thinking you might want to explore `?list.dirs` with full.names = TRUE and recursive = TRUE. It is not clear what you want when you say 'combine' latest from B,C & etc. Is the goal to change the underlying directory structure, i.e. move all the 'latest' to one place?

Comment: @Chris I want to list all the files in different folders. There are levels to my files. The common part to all directories is "/Users/ritikakhurana/Open Modeling Group Dropbox/COACCH/climate/A" then I have subfolder after that. These subfolders have different names (B, C, D, E, F). Then in those subfolders, I have their subfolders (historical and latest). I want to list all files of "historical" folder of B subfolder. I hope I have explained it better this time.